# SQL Multiple Joins returning error 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'JOIN'.'

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I'm very new to SQL and trying some multiple joins with SQL Server.

Given

`c_slpn`:

```
"ID Name    Age Salary"
'1  Abe     61  140000'
'2  Bob     34  44000'
'5  Chris   34  40000'
'7  Dan     41  52000'
'8  Ken     57  115000'
'11 Joe     38  38000'
```

`c_cust`:

```
"ID Name    City    Industry Type"
'4  Comp1    pleasant   J'
'6  Comp2    oaktown        J'
'7  Comp3    jackson        B'
'9  Comp4    Jackson        B'
```

`c_ordr`:

```
"Number order_date  cust_id salesperson_id  Amount"
'10     8/2/96      4       2        540'
'20     1/30/99     4       8        1800'
'30     7/14/95     9       1        460'
'40     1/29/98     7       2        2400'
'50     2/3/98      6       7        600'
'60     3/2/98      6       7        720'
'70     5/6/98      9       7        150'
```

I should find 'List salespeople that have an order with 'Comp1', but the script below is throwing an error:

> Line 6 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'JOIN'.

Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM  c_cust
JOIN C_ordr ON C_ordr.cust_id=  c_cust.ID   
WHERE NAME = 'Comp1'
JOIN c_slpn ON c_slpn.id=c_ordr.cust_id
```

Please help me..., I'm stuck :-p [This is my 1st question, am I missing something]

Comment: Which of two _mutually exclusive RDBMS_ are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WHERE` clause goes after `JOIN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM  c_cust
JOIN C_ordr ON C_ordr.cust_id = c_cust.ID   
JOIN c_slpn ON c_slpn.id = c_ordr.salesperson_id
WHERE c_cust.NAME = 'Comp1'
```

You can also do it in the `JOIN` clause like `C_ordr.cust_id = c_cust.ID AND c_cust.NAME = 'Comp1'`, by the way.

Comment: Thanks for the the reply @notulysses But using the query gives me blank output..

'SELECT *'
'FROM  c_cust'
'JOIN C_ordr ON C_ordr.cust_id=c_cust.ID'
'JOIN c_slpn ON c_slpn.id =c_ordr.cust_id'
'WHERE c_cust.NAME= 'Comp1' ' Still confused... ;(

Comment: Are you sure there are records with matching conditions?

Comment: Yes, c_cust.Name has Comp1 having c_cust.id 4 matching with cust_id.cust_id. AND cust_id.salesperson_id match c_slpn.ID. ( @IsabelHM thanks for the edits)

Comment: I got the correct query now.
Instead of  
'JOIN c_slpn ON c_slpn.id=c_ordr.cust_id' ,
I should have put 
'JOIN c_slpn ON c_slpn.id =c_ordr.salesperson_id' . I did wrong while entering the column name of table c_ordr. Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: @Aju Mohan: You are welcome, don't forget to mark as answered.

Comment: sure.., I will add as answered

Comment: @Aju Mohan: It was autocorrect, not _make_, _mark_ - ✓.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if it was just typo but your table name is inconsistent.

```
SELECT *
FROM  c_cust
JOIN c_ordr
ON c_ordr.cust_id=  c_cust.ID   
JOIN c_slpn
ON c_slpn.id=c_ordr.cust_id
WHERE c_cust.Name= 'Comp1'
```

Comment: corrected query now.
'JOIN c_slpn ON c_slpn.id=c_ordr.salesperson_id' . I keyed-in the column name for c_ordr incorectly :p  Thank you for looking into my query :D